# Initiating pop-up before accessing .net out-of-the-box web map?

Tags: arcgis-server, .net

I need to create a pop-up that initiates as soon as a user clicks on a web map, or accesses the link from another location. The map is an ArcGIS Server out-of-the-box .net app. It's for a disclaimer and just needs an accept and do not accept button. I could do it easily enough if it were Flex or Silverlight, but I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MapClick (double click on the map) or PreRender event of the Map Component:

```
Protected Sub Map1_MapClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.PointEventArgs) Handles Map1.MapClick
 'PopUp code here
End Sub
```

Comment: And, after the disclaimer is shown, signal that the user has seen it (via a class-level variable, for example) so that it doesn't pop up the _next_ time they click on the map.

Comment: Yeah, don't forget that or it will be very annoying for your users.